# Scientific notation with infinity rule disabled

Tags: javascript, calculator, scientific-notation, infinity

I keep trying to make my result in scientific notation and still have the infinity rule outlawed, but I can't seem to get it to work. When I use the toExponential() function, it responds with an error message.  Please may I have some help? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Base:<input id="n1" rows=1 cols=3 type=number">
Exponent:<input id="n2" rows=1 cols=3 type="number">
<script>
var calc=0
function calculate() {
   calc=document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
   BigInt(document.getElementById("n1").value)**BigInt(document.getElementById("n2").value)
   calc.toExponential()=document.getElementById("result");
}
   </script>
   <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><p>=<span id="result" style=display:none></span> 
   </p>
   <script src="decimal.js/decimal.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide error message you received ?

Comment: With this new way of writing it out, I no longer have an error message, but for somereason BigInt no longer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toExponential doesn't exists on BigInt. Since `toExponential()` exists in `Number.prototype.toExponential()`, you need to parse BingInt to float and then call toExponential().

```js
function calculate() {
  let calc = BigInt(document.getElementById("n1").value)**BigInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = parseFloat(calc).toExponential();
  console.log(parseFloat(calc).toExponential());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Base:<input id="n1" rows=1 cols=3 type=number">
Exponent:<input id="n2" rows=1 cols=3 type="number">
   <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button><p>=<span id="result"></span> 
   </p>
   
   </body>
   </html>
```